# Как сделать как вконтакте: линии вертикальные и горизонтальные?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать как вконтакте: линии вертикальные и горизонтальные?

Comment: конкретнее


Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="border-left:1px solid black">Блок с вертикальной границей слева</div>
<div style="border-right:1px solid black">Блок с вертикальной границей справа</div>
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid black">Блок с горизонтальной границей снизу</div>
<div style="border-top:1px solid black">Блок с горизонтальной границей сверху</div>
```

То же самое можно проделывать с ячейками таблицы. А еще есть тег `<hr>`, который рисует горизонтальную черту.